# Example of a bounded set with a minimum but no maximum

Tags: general-topology

Using the definition of a bounded set to be a set where there exists a positive number M>0 such that every element of the set s < M.

How could you then have a set without a maximum? Surely M is the maximum?

Comment: $[0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: `M is the maximum?` No, M is just an upper bound. For example $123$ is an upper bound of $[0,1)$.

Comment: Btw you don't have the definition of "bounded"  right: Say $S=(-\infty,2)=\{x:x<2\}$. Every element of $$ is less than $M=2$ but $S$ is not bounded...

Comment: What would the correct definition of bounded be?

Comment: A subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ is bounded iff there exists $M\in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall x\in S\;(|x|<M).$ Also, $S$ is bounded iff there exist $A,B\in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall x\in S\;(A<x<B).$..If there exists $M\in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall x\in S\;(x<M)$ then $ S$ is bounded above. If  $m\in \Bbb R$ and $\forall x\in S\;(m<x)$ then  $S$ is bounded below.  The maximum of  S is  the largest $member$ of $S,$ which might not exist.  Example: The set of negative reals has a least upper bound ($0$) but $0$ is not a negative real, and there is no largest negative real.

Answer (score 1):

The interval $[0,1)$ is the easiest example.